# GCM Pushnotification not received, though GCM server reported as sent successfully

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

So, I am sending push notification to thousands of my users. I have noticed that GCM server respond back with "messageId" and according to the documentation it is successfully sent to the user, but the user (one of our internal device) did not receive the notification. And this happens very randomly, same device receives the notification sometimes. Is this normal? if not what could be the possible reason behind this and what would be the fix?

Thanks
Riz

Answer (score 0):

Though not a complete list, the issue could be any of the following:

- The affected phones were not online/connected at the time of the message being sent.
- Your setup uses a *collapse key*, which would collapse prior messages being sent under the same collapse key (thus the reason your device only receives some notifications and not all).
- The affected phones were asleep/locked, and you did not implement a *Wakeful Broadcast Receiver* in your client app.